# NSString vs %i with stringWithFormat

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, stringwithformat

Ok I am not sure how or why this is working but if someone could explain this to me it would be greatly appreciated.

I am debugging an iPhone app and Xcode gives me the following warning, which is correct: "Format Specifies type 'int' but the Argument has a Type 'NSString'.

The code below returns a number, but if I set it to a string it returns a very long string. I know that they wanted the integer and not the string, but I do not know why this would return a number for a string because when I do change it using [str intValue] I get "0" not the long number.  So how is this working, can someone explain this to me?

Here is the code:

```
- (void) FooBar:(NSString *)myStr
{
  NSString *callback = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some Text Here(%i)", myStr];

  [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:callback];
}
```

---

Ok let me show you what I mean, and don't worry about the string being passed please. I just want to know how it produces a number like what is shown below from it. I did three NSLogs:

```
- (void) FooBar:(NSString *)myStr
{
  NSString *callback = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some Text Here(%i)", myStr];
    NSLog(@"NSString = %@", myStr);
    NSLog(@"Percent i = %i", myStr);
    NSLog(@"Percent i = %i", [myStr intValue]);

  [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:callback];
}
```

Results:

```
NSString = /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.8mi&utmn=1220166202&utmt=event&utme=5(Init*shoutzVersion*iPhone%20Simulator)(1)&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=320x480&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmac=UA-28151051-1&utmcc=__utma%3D1.1697021890.1347557664.1348092917.1348092961.195%3B&utmht=1348092961213&utmqt=9984

Percent i = 154448576

Percent i = 0
```

Anyone know why this happens?

Thank You!

Comment: Aaaand euh, btw the compiler is right and your question doesn't quite make sense to me... Could you elaborate? What do you expect? What's that string that is supposed to be an integer?

Answer (score 1):

Since the question was "what does this incorrect code do" and not "how to fix it":

```
NSString *callback = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some Text Here(%i)", myStr];
```

myStr is an NSString*. %i is a format for an int. So you are passing an NSString*, when the stringWithFormat method expects an int.

Officially, this is "undefined behaviour" which means absolutely anything can happen.

In practice, you run this code one a 32 bit or 64 bit computer or iPhone. "int" will be 32 bits in all cases. myStr is an NSString*, which will be either 32 bits or 64 bits. Running on a 32 bit computer, it is most likely that stringWithFormat takes the 32 bits of the pointer, pretends that they are the 32 bits of an int, and prints them accordingly, so usually you get a big number; if myStr == nil you likely get a 0 printed. That number is just a number of no use to anyone.

On a 64 bit computer, myStr is a 64 bit pointer. Most likely, 32 bits out the 64 bits will be interpreted as an int and printed that way. Then there are 32 bits left. Since you are not trying to print any other parameters, those 32 bits will be ignored and cause no harm. If you used

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some text %i some number %i", myStr, 117];
```

on a 64 bit computer then quite likely the second %i would pick up the remaining 32 bits of the myStr pointer and not the number 117. If you used

```
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some number %i some text %@", myStr, myStr];
```

that would likely be fatal on a 64 bit computer. Most likely the %i picks up the first 32 bits of myStr. The %@ picks up the other 32 bits of the first myStr, plus another 32 bits, giving a completely messed up pointer, and trying to print this will most likely crash.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting [str intValue] result 0 if number(long number in your case) is out of range. Try [str floatValue] or [str doubleValue] and see the result.

Comment: You would want %f for float and %d for double value.

Comment: I thought he is trying stringWithFormat because [str intValue] returs 0 which is not expected by him. BTW for double, it's %ld! %d is for Integer!

Comment: %ld STILL isn't double, it's long.

Comment: Ok everyone lets see if I can explain what I am asking. First I know how to fix or change it so that is not what I am asking. The original programmer did this on purpose to get a number and not the string value. I want to know how and why does this return a number?  When I look at the string value it is a very long path type command, but when it is %i is a number like "1232089", if I do something like  str doublevalue or any other number format, I get 0.  So the %i is converting the string into a number value and I don't know how it can do this.  Does that make sense?

Comment: isn't "ld" means long double? :)

Comment: what you mean why does it return number? %d, %D and %i all represent Signed 32-bit integers. if myStr is "123", %i will print 123 but if it is "123FooText", it will print 0 or garbage number I think. There will be implicit conversation happening! You must be getting warning at this line though as you are trying to use %i instead of %@!

Comment: Ok let me show you what I mean. I did two NSLogs:                     NSString = /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.8mi&utmn=1126555104&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=320x480&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmp=%2Flogin&utmac=UA-28151051-1&utmcc=__utma     and      %i = 154475504

Comment: That doesn't make any sense buddy! Could you please edit your question and give different scenarios you tried and what is your question is each scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) FooBar:(NSString *)myStr
{
  NSString *callback = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some Text Here(%@)", myStr];

  [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:callback];
}
```

Comment: You just used the wrong thing. %i display integer %f display float %@ display string etc.